# C# Get Audio Volume For Each Speaker In 7.1 Audio

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, audio, waveform

Today I was trying to make simple C# application to display real-time volume of system sound. I have success with [NAudio library](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) using this code:

```
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
var device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Console);

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("\r{0}", device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue);
}

// Output: 0,2314617
```

The problem is that I want to get audio volume of each speaker of my 7.1 audio system instead of master volume, so the output will look like:

```
Speaker1: 0,435462
Speaker2: 0,237462
Speaker3: 0,535962
Speaker4: 0,335862
Speaker5: 0,835462
Speaker6: 0,635462
Speaker7: 0,335462
Subwoofer: 0,236562
```

Is there any way I can do it? If there is a way can you provide an example?

Comment: You are probably looking for [`PeakValues`](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/e359ca0566e9f9b14fee1ba6e0ec17e4482c7844/NAudio/CoreAudioApi/AudioMeterInformation.cs#L47) instead of `MasterPeakValue`.

Comment: @RomanR. Oh yeeahh! Thank you very much! I don´t know how I could not see it before.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Roman R. comment I figured out this solution:

```
    var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
    var device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Console);

    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0;i< device.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues.Count;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: " + i + " : " + device.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues[i]);
        }
    }
```